# why does x -= x + 4 return -4 instead of 4

Tags: python, operators, assignment-operator

new to python and trying to wrestle with the finer points of assignment operators. Here's my code and then the question.

```
  x = 5
  print(x)
  x -= x + 4
  print(x)
```

the above code, returns 5 the first time, but yet -4 upon the second print.  In my head I feel that the number should actually be 4 as I am reading this as 
x= x - x +4.  However, I know that is wrong as python is returning -4 instead.  I would be gracious if anyone could explain to me (in simple terms as I am a novice) as I have been really pounding my head over the table on this one.

Comment: `x-=x+4` means `5-(5+4)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x -= x + 4` can be written as:

```
x = x - (x + 4) = x - x - 4 = -4
```

Comment: thanks! I realized that shortly after I posted this but...hopefully someone in the same boat will see this and not make my mistake :P

Comment: Of course, it would be much better written as `x = -4`.